# angular api is automatically getting called two times?

Tags: angularjs

In my project am requesting for data from the API and am passing the sessionid in the header section of the `$http` call. Now what happens when this $http call is getting triggered and in back-end this is called by two times first time with sessioID=null and second time with the actual session id value. Am getting data some time and sometime not getting because of this. How to fix this

Below is my code please check.

**Controller.js**

```
getAllSurveyService.surveyList().then(
      function( data ) {
        $scope.allProjects = data;
          $scope.allSurveys = data[0].Surveys;
          if($scope.allSurveys.ErrorMessage){
            AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
          }
      }
  );
```

**getAllSurveyService.js**

```
angular
    .module('adminsuite')
    .service('getAllSurveyService', getAllSurveyService);
    getAllSurveyService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$state'];
     function getAllSurveyService($http,$cookieStore,$rootScope,$timeout,$state){
        var session = $cookieStore.get('globals');
            var data = {
                sessionId : session.currentUser.session
            }
            $rootScope.token = session.currentUser.session;
            var requestData = JSON.stringify(surveyData)   
            this.surveyList = function () {
                return $http.get(__env.apiUrl+'/UserSurvey/GetAllSurveys',  {
                                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','SessionID':$rootScope.token}
                                })
                .then(function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                            return response.data;
                        }, function(error){
                             console.log("error");
                              console.log(error);
                            return error;
                        });
            }

    };
```

Comment: From the official angularJs Website:  Note: The $cookieStore service is deprecated. Please use the $cookies service instead.

Comment: "cookie writes are flushed asynchronously, which makes it hard to predict when the cookie will be picked by other browser apis like XMLHttpRequest used by $http" from: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6411